# What is the best way to define logic for web-streams sources/sinks?

Tags: javascript, stream

I'm using the new web-streams-polyfill and its unclear to me the best way to define and/or add extended functionality to a web streams.  Especially if the streams are somewhat long-lived.

In particular, and for a decent example, I want to use a webRTC data channel as a readable stream source.  This data channel can be paused either by backpressure or programatically.

I've found a few possible patterns in both the spec and my experimenting:

1. Extend the stream class:

```
class DataChannelStream extends ReadableStream {
  constructor(dataChannel) {
    super({
      // source methods (cant use `this`)
      start: () => { ... }
      pull: () => { ... }
      cancel: () => { ... }
    })
    this.dataChannel = dataChannel
  }

  // extra methods
  pause() { ... }
  resume() { ... }
}
```

One issue I run into with this one is the challenge of having to pass the source methods into `super` without referencing `this`, which is required since it is before the `super` call.  A benefit seems to be that your resulting stream will have the extra `pause`/`resume` methods directly on it.

2. Define the source separately, wrap the source to use as stream:

```
class DataChannelSource {
  constructor(dataChannel) {
    this.dataChannel = dataChannel
  }
  // source methods
  start: () => { ... }
  pull: () => { ... }
  cancel: () => { ... }  

  // extra methods
  pause() { ... }
  resume() { ... }
}

// elsewhere....
function createDataChannelStream (dataChannel) {
  const source = new DataChannelSource(dataChannel)
  const stream = new ReadableStream(source)
  return { source, stream }
}
```

In this pattern, the extra methods are attached to the source, instead of the stream, which makes for a less compelling, but maybe more explicit
 api.

3. Just use custom classes which make use of streams, but are not actually sources:

```
class DataChannelSource {
  constructor(dataChannel) {
    this.dataChannel = dataChannel
  }

  pipeTo(dest) {
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
      // source methods
      start: () => { ... }
      pull: () => { ... }
      cancel: () => { ... }  
    })
    return stream.pipeTo(dest)
  }

  // extra methods
  pause() { ... }
  resume() { ... }
}
```

I don't really like redefining the `pipeTo` api here, but we could also just do something like `getStream` and return the stream.

One last note, I kind of wish we could just extend the base class and define our source methods as members of the child, rather than having to pass them into `super`.  Is there a good reason this design is not allowed?

```
class DataChannelStream extends ReadableStream {
  constructor(dataChannel) {
    super()
    this.dataChannel = dataChannel
  }

  // source methods
  start: () => { ... }
  pull: () => { ... }
  cancel: () => { ... }  

  // extra methods
  pause() { ... }
  resume() { ... }
}
```

Given the examples above, the top three patterns seem to work, but obviously provide different APIs.  So it may end up coming down to taste/design.

I am wondering if someone could help guide me on intended use or if anyone has come up with best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a variant of option 3 where you use use a getter named `readable` to return the stream, for consistency with web standards.

See https://wicg.github.io/web-transport/#incomingstream for an example of this kind of API.

Option 1 will provide good ease-of-use but I don't like the use of inheritance of implementation, and as you mentioned, constructing it will be tricky.

Option 2 feels like a lot of boilerplate to me.

The reason why `start`, `pull` and `cancel` are not exposed on the ReadableStream object is to provide a clean separation between the API to create a stream and the API to consume a stream.

Jake Archibald's "2016 - the year of web streams" is the best article I know of for how to "think in streams", but I'm eager to hear of any others.